# margins in \enumerate

Tags: spacing

In LaTeX, I want to `\enumerate` some `\item`s which are in fact small paragraphs.

I will use `\alph`, so the labels will read (a), (b), (c) and so forth

I want the symbols (a), (b) and so forth to be indented, and then the "body" of the `\item` to be flushleft. I have written:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{label=(\alph*)}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item about 5 lines of prose, here
\item maybe another five lines or so
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

With this done, the "five lines of prose" are all slightly indented instead of being flush with the left margin.

Comment: Don't combine the use of [`enumerate`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumerate) *and* [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem). They compete for the same real estate.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem):

[image]

or you can create your own `myenumerate` environment:

[image]

The above two options are included in the minimal example below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,lipsum}
\setlist[enumerate]{label=(\alph*),wide=0pt}

\newenvironment{myenumerate}
  {\setcounter{enumi}{0}% Restart enumerate numbering
   \renewcommand{\theenumi}{\alph{enumi}}% Number represenation
   \par\addvspace{\topsep}% Skip above environment
   \renewcommand{\item}{\par\addvspace{\itemsep}\noindent
     \refstepcounter{enumi}%
     (\theenumi)~\ignorespaces}}
  {\par\addvspace{\topsep}}% Skip below environment
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item \lipsum[1]
  \item \lipsum[2]
\end{enumerate}

\begin{myenumerate}
  \item \lipsum[1]
  \item \lipsum[2]
\end{myenumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Bernard: Ugh... that's far more betterer. I'll update my answer.